# How to reference spawned objects in a scene? (closed)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My game has objects which are spawned in different places, and there are always different amounts.

When the player touches this object, the object disappears, and 1 point is added to the variable `point`.

I need to count the number of ALL of these objects in the scene and then compare this number against `point`.  And if `point` is equal to the initial number of objects on the scene, then a specific event will occur.

My problem is that I somehow need to count the number of spawned objects.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases I prefer to have a dedicated component on my prefab which allows to simply count/iterate the instances directly:

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static readonly HashSet<Example> _instances = new();

    public static IReadOnlyCollection<Example> Instances => _instances;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        _instances.Add(this);
    }

    private void OnDestroy ()
    {
        _instances.Remove();
    }
}
```

this way any other object can get the current alive instances via

```
var amount = Example.Instances.Count;

foreach(var instance in Example.Instances)
{
    ...
}
```